# onerror event xhr js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброе утро. Что должно произойти, чтобы сработал onerror xhr? Сервер иногда возвращает json данные с кодом 500, и согласно логике в этом случае должно произойти onerror, но происходит onload.

```
var requestError = function () {
    console.log("error", this);
};
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'https://core.lotus-app.ru/1/' + method, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = success;
    xhr.onerror = requestError;
    xhr.timeout = timeout;
    xhr.vars = vars;
    xhr.send(paramToURL(params));
```

[image: код 500]

Comment: А сервер код 500 точно отдает? просто некоторые отдают код 200, а в json код 500 :D

Comment: json данные с кодом 500 и код 500 — разные вещи. Соответственно сервер должен вернуть не `Status Code:200OK` с json, а 500. На сервере, например php будет это выглядеть как-то так `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Сервер отдает 500 в status code, в консоли браузера этот код так же наблюдается.

Comment: Пока сделал так: в onload добавил проверку response и если не 200 то вызываю onerror. Есть ли возможность сделать это без этих костылей?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
согласно логике в этом случае должно произойти onerror
```

Нет, не должно.
onerror срабатывает при возникновении ошибок **сетевого** уровня.
Т.е. если запрос вообще не вернулся или отклонен согласно кроссдоменным ограничениям.

Если http запрос вообще вернулся, даже и с кодом ошибки, то onerror не сработает.

Надо использовать `onreadystatechange` и проверять там код завершения запроса.

Еще лучше сразу взять какую-то обертку для работы с сетью на уровне которой эта тонкость, а также множество тонкостей с которыми Вы еще не столкнулись, разрешены за вас. Будь то `fetch-polyfill`, `axios` или даже `$.ajax` в случае если у вас jQuery все равное есть.

Comment: Такое поведение обусловлено спецификацией XHR или это такая реализация спецификации отдельными браузерами?

Comment: @Dmitry, спецификацией насколько я знаю, потому что такое поведение кажется везде. Но конкретную строчку спецификации я с ходу не нашел.